# Is anybody runnning Google Stenographer on their Ubuntu machine?

Tags: google, open-source

I am trying to install the Google [Stenographer](https://github.com/google/stenographer) tool on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine.  Is there anyone that is familiar with this tool and/or running it on one of their machines?  I have it installed - by all accounts correctly - but when I try to run the tool the following keeps showing up in the logs:

stenographer[pid] could not read config file "/etc/stenographer/config": read /etc/stenographer/config: is a directory

I thought changing the location in stenographer.go to look for the config.go file in the above directory would fix the problem, but it has not.  At this point I suspect there may be something in the executable pointing to the above directory instead of the .go file, but I'm not certain.

If there is anybody who could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Jeff Suchomel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That path should not be a directory. It should be the config file. The problem is it somehow is a directory instead of a file.

Comment: Dobey - thank you.  And I agree 100% with your reply.  I guess what I'm asking is, does anyone know how I can find (or confirm) what is referencing that directory path, so that I might be able to change that to reference the config file and not the directory?

Comment: At this points I think it might be the executable in /usr/bin, but that's just an assumption on my part.  :-)

Comment: It doesn't matter what is referencing it. The problem is that it was installed incorrectly, and that path is a directory, rather than the config file. Did you manage to create it as a directory when installing, and then end up with the config file being copied into it?

Comment: Hi Dobey.  I followed the instructions to install at the following URLs, but I didn't create anything, that appeared to be done by Go, but I did end up with a config file that needed to be copied into it.   https://github.com/google/stenographer/blob/master/INSTALL.md       https://github.com/google/stenographer/blob/master/README.md

Comment: But did you delete the `/etc/stenographer/config/` directory and replace it with `sudo cp steno.conf /etc/stenographer/config`instead? It seems like you perhaps misinterpreted the instructions, and did `mkdir /etc/stenographer/config` and then copied the file into that directory, rather than just doing the `cp` as I mentioned.

Comment: Ok.  I see what you mean now.  I did as you suggested (deleted /etc/.... and then cp steno.conf).  That got me further.  Now I'm running in to what the logs are telling me is a permissions issue.  No matter what I try, the logs read the following after each attempt to start Stenographer:

Comment: stenographer: Stenotype stopped after x.xxxxxms:  cannot start stenotype: fork/exec /etc/stenographer/stenotype:  permission denied

Comment: I have verified multiple times the proper permissions are in place per the instructions (/etc/stenographer root:root/0755  and   /etc/stenographer/certs stenographer:stenographer/0750), and I have tried executing from different directories (per my internet research) but no luck.  Any ideas???  Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm guessing it's a similar issue. I don't know why it's expecting a script there in `/etc/` but the `/etc/stenographer/stenotype` file should be a script and executable, and not a directory. But this is getting a bit extensive, while your original question has been answered. Long discussions really aren't suitable for Ask Ubuntu (and the StackExchange) format, and would be better on the forum or such.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for your help, Dobey.  Much appreciated.